# Change column display in Power BI power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a fiscal year column, fiscal period, and fiscal quarter.
The Fiscal Quarter column is calculated by dividing the fiscal period by 3 then rounding up the number.
As a result, the values in this column appear as 1, 2, 3,...etc.

I want to change how the values appear so that they are displayed as "Qtr - FY" (e.g, Q1 - FY2021) in the same column that contains the calculation formula, preferably by getting this info from the available columns.
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [CONCATENATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/concatenate-function-dax#:%7E:text=If%20you%20need%20to%20concatenate,string%20in%20double%20quotation%20marks.)

```
CONCATENATE(<text1>, <text2>)
```

Concatenate multiple columns:

```
=CONCATENATE( [FirstName]&" ", CONCATENATE( IF( LEN([MiddleName])>1, LEFT([MiddleName],1)&" ", ""), [LastName]))
```

To add static values in between columns, follow this.

```
= "Q" & [fiscal quarter] & " - FY" & [fiscal year]
```

Read more on [How to concatenate multiple column in Power BI](https://ipradeep.medium.com/power-bi-how-to-concatenate-of-multiple-column-in-a-single-column-f6ef8703fd5e)

Comment: [FirstName], [MiddleName] and [LastName] are column names. According to your example, it should be fiscal year, fiscal period and fiscal quarter

Comment: ok, but this just just concats numbers togeether.
I need to write letters and perform calculations  at the same time in the same column (quarter)

Comment: @Michael Answer updated. Can't provide an exact answer without what you have done so far. Please update the question with your code / screenshots.